# mkdirs() return false with write external permission

Tags: android

I've a problem with mkdirs function. See my permissions manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="xxxxxx"
android:versionCode="15"
android:versionName="3.1.1508">

<!-- Global permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And my code

```
String APP_PATH_SD_CARD = "/xxxxx";
    String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + APP_PATH_SD_CARD;

    if(!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){
        ToastDressmup.make(this, "External SD card not mounted", 0, ToastAction.CLOSE.getValue()).show();
    }

    try {
        File dir = new File(fullPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        ==> My file doesn't exist
```

SD card is mounted. I don't understand. I read very answers on internet, but it's still wrong.

I was tested on emulator (with emulated sdcard) and on Nexus 5, it's doesn't work. On my HTC One X it's work, why ?! I'me desperate

Thank you for all!
G.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mkdirs returns false for directory on sd card while the parent directory is writable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062357/mkdirs-returns-false-for-directory-on-sd-card-while-the-parent-directory-is-writ)

Comment: Thx! But their solutions do not fix my problem :( I was tested mkdirs(), mkdir on each directory, with emulator or without. I haven't more ideas :(

Comment: If you are using Android6, check the answer of easyspeek here. The permission handling has changed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/cant-get-the-permission

Comment: My link was missing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android/33292700#33292700

Comment: Waouuuu, you're right @DenisLukenich! With previous API is good. I will search the true permission now ;) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As solved in the comments, the answer is that the permission was missing.

Since Android 6 the permission handling has changed as stated:

[Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android/33292700#33292700)

or

[Android permission doesn't work even if I have declared it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/cant-get-the-permission)

You need to gather these permissions at runtime again:

> Quote from first answer:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
>  *
>  * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to grant permissions
>  *
>  * @param activity
>  */
> public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
>     // Check if we have write permission
>     int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
>
>     if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>         // We don't have permission so prompt the user
>         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
>                 activity,
>                 PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
>                 REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>         );
>     }
> }
> ```