# android not creating folder in LOLLIPOP and up

Tags: java, android

i seem to be having problems creating folders in LOLLIPOP and up although code works just fine for previous versions 
there is no error in the log-cast it simply does not crate the folder can someone help

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "reelyChat/vids");

    if(!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
            try {
                mediaStorageDir.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            if(!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("reelyChat", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO){
        vid_name = "RC_"+my_user_id+"_profile.mp4";
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + vid_name);
    }else{
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me on Marshmallow, are you granting the run-time permission required for Marshmallow?

Comment: If the suggestion by @SteveM does not work, look here for some other suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062357/mkdirs-returns-false-for-directory-on-sd-card-while-the-parent-directory-is-writ

Comment: @Steve M yes permissions are set it just doesn't create the file in lollypop but i haven't tried on marshmallow yet all other previous versions work tho

Comment: Try this it may be work stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need write permission at run time.

//Just call this function

getWirtePermissionAndCreateDir();

```
private void getWirtePermissionAndCreateDir() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {            
            createDir();

        } else {
            final String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            //Asking request Permissions
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, 9);
        }
    }   

     @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

        boolean writeAccepted = false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 9:
                writeAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                break;
        }
        if (writeAccepted) {
           createDir();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "You don't assign permission.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void createDir(){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "reelyChat/vids");
        mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have took permissions but not at run time. Device running on Marshmallow or above needs to take permissions at run time.
For more information visit [Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)